# Cropping the center of an image : Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image which is resize to 128x128. I want to crop the center of the image(which is the ROI) with , a square of n size.

I know cropping can be done by

```
 imcrop
```

and center of an image can be found out using

```
 center=size(I)/2+.5.
```

How can I use this two information togather inorder to crop the center part of my image

Comment: Nice that you managed to solve this problem on your own. In the spirit of this site, it would be nice to show your solution - or to delete the question...

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI Post it as an answer, and accept it

Answer (score 5):

```
II = imread('img.png')
[p3, p4] = size(II);
q1 = 50; // size of the crop box
i3_start = floor((p3-q1)/2); % or round instead of floor; using neither gives warning
i3_stop = i3_start + q1;

i4_start = floor((p4-q1)/2);
i4_stop = i4_start + q1;

II = II(i3_start:i3_stop, i4_start:i4_stop, :);
figure ,imshow(II);
```

this will do the same which I asked:-)